# Different HTML files linked to one CSS file with exact same styled header, but displayed different style on webpage

Tags: html, css

I linked different HTML files to one CSS file and set the style of header to be exactly the same, but when I click "Team" in the navigation, the header part is shrunk compared to the click of "Home" or " History". Thank you guys for the help and explanation.

[This is what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hbc2.jpg)

[In this pic, the header/navigation background is shrunk when you click "Team", but it works fine (like the pic I expected) when
you click "Home" or "History"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqWMo.jpg)

I post "Home" HTML file here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ultimate-Frisbee: Home</title>
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw2.css">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <h1>Ultimate Frisbee</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="cssassignment.html" class="active">home</a>
    <a href="team.html">team</a>
    <a href="history.html">history</a>
    <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html">USA ultimate</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <aside class="half">
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp">
      <img src="images/a.jpg"
           alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo"
           title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/>
      <!--      here we used title attribute, which specifies extra information about the img, but it can't replace alt, because when the
      img can't be displayed for some reason, then screen reader will read alt content rather than title attribute, also, title attribute
      can be used in any elements in html tags-->
    </a>
    <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg">
      <img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005"
           src="images/b.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee">
      <img src="images/c.jpg"
           alt="Ultimate Frisbee">
    </a>
  </aside>
  <section class="half">
    <h2>Watch your Head </h2>
    <p>Ultimate Frisbee is a sport that I never played myself, but it's popularity is something
      hard to ignore in many Midwestern college towns.  Students (and people who wish they were
      still students) spend the few briefs months of good weather, sprinting down fields, hurling
      frisbees, and yelling "Stack!!".</p>
    <p>What I find much more entertaining is the large number of people who continue to play when
      the weather gets windy and the night sky darkens around oh....4:15pm.  The sight of frisbees
      boomeranging in the wind is topped only by the knowledge that even when you can't seem, those
      same plastic discs of death are probably hurtling through the dark night sky at 8 or 9 o'clock
      in the evening.</p>
    <p>Ultimate Frisbee requires a great deal of stamina and dexterity.  Not surprisingly,
      the <abbr title="international olympic committee "> IPO </abbr> officially recognized Ultimate
      as a sport in 2015.   It can go up against other sports for inclusion in  Olympic games.</p>
  <p>add a new repo for python in github</p>
  </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

I post my "Team" html file here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ultimate-Frisbee: Home</title>
  <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw2.css">
<!--  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />-->
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <h1>Ultimate Frisbee</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="cssassignment.html">home</a>
    <a href="team.html" class="active">team</a>
    <a href="history.html">history</a>
    <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html">USA ultimate</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <aside class="half">
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp">
      <img src="images/a.jpg"
           alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo"
           title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/>
      <!--      here we used title attribute, which specifies extra information about the img, but it can't replace alt, because when the
      img can't be displayed for some reason, then screen reader will read alt content rather than title attribute, also, title attribute
      can be used in any elements in html tags-->
    </a>
    <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg">
      <img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005"
           src="images/b.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee">
      <img src="images/c.jpg"
           alt="Ultimate Frisbee">
    </a>
  </aside>

  <section class="half">
    <h2>College Teams</h2>
    <p>This is not meant to be a comprehensive list of all the teams, just a sampling from around
       the united states. I focused on the ones that I though bad cools names.</p>


  <section>
    <table class="cal">
      <thead>
      <tr><th class="head">Team Name</th><th>Location</th><th>League Type</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td class="blank">Afterburn</td> <td class="body">Colorado</td> <td class="body">Men's</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Cold Front</td> <td class="body">Maine</td> <td class="body">Women's</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Disco Inferno</td> <td class="body">Rhode Island</td> <td class="body">Women's</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Bad Habit</td> <td class="body">Washington DC</td> <td class="body">Men's</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Jive Turkeys</td> <td class="body">Pennsylvania</td> <td class="body">Both</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Knights of the Round Disc</td> <td class="body">Virginia</td> <td class="body">Men's</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Ninjas</td> <td class="body">Minnesota</td> <td class="body">Women's</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Flying Squirrels</td> <td class="body">Arizona</td> <td class="body">Men's</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Superfly</td> <td class="body">Connecticut</td> <td class="body">Men's</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="blank">Flywheel</td> <td class="body">Michigan</td> <td class="body">Women's</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>

  </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

I post part of my CSS file here:

```
body {
    margin: 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
    background-image: url("../images/d.jpg");
    /*background-color: blanchedalmond;*/
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 250%;
}
nav>a {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-family: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    margin: 7%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
}
nav .active {
    background-color: #ce6153;
}
aside {
    width: 12%;
    line-height: 45px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    padding: 1%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4%;
}
aside img {
    width: 90%;
    height: 40%;
    display: block;
    margin: 4%;
    background-size: 300px 100px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
table {
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 60%;
    font-family: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    transform: translate(10%, 3%);
/*    the translate attribute of transform is used to locate the table which corner it should be at or toward*/
}
td, th {
    padding-left: 8px;
}
/*attention:  if you add border to the table, then table has border, not the head of table, so for the radius of the thead,
you need to add border to th rather than table or thead.but the head of thead. check the structure of table in html*/
th {
    border: 1px solid #e6b0b0;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 255, 153,0), rgba(0,255,153,1));
}

.head {
    text-align: left;
}

tbody {
    background-color: #78a757;
}

.body {
    text-align: center;
}

tbody td{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

tbody:hover td {
    opacity: 1;
}

section .half{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Check `<head>` (`<link rel="stylesheet"...`): You are including different css files in both html files.

Comment: The linked pictures look identically. Is the given css code part of the content of hw2.css?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I tried  and  this time on both html file, but it is still different, when I click "Home", the header part was what i want,but when I click "Team", the header part dynamically moved to bottom right corner, when i click those two navs, I can see it was dynamically moving. from the pic, you may notice the header part was a little shrinked on "Team"

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question, so please don’t post it as one. If you need to clarify things, respond to people’s comments _with_ a comment, or edit your question if you have more additional info to add.